# Unable to find a valid way to instantiate a template function using bitset

Tags: c++, templates, linker

I have a template function declared in bit_tools.h

```
template <size_t sizeA, size_t sizeB, size_t sizeAB>
std::bitset<sizeAB> join2(std::bitset<sizeA> bsetA,\
                           std::bitset<sizeB> bsetB);
```

Here is the definition of join2 in bit_tools.cc

```
template <size_t sizeA, size_t sizeB, size_t sizeAB>
std::bitset<sizeAB> join2(std::bitset<sizeA> bsetA, std::bitset<sizeB> bsetB){
    return std::bitset<sizeAB>(bsetA.to_string + bsetB.to_string);
```

After trying to use join2 in main.cpp I get a linker error as expected. I have read of methods that involve putting a line in .cpp file that instantiates the template. However given that bitset must have a nontype template parameter im not sure what i should do?

Ideally i would do something like this

```
template std::bitset<int>  join2<int,int,int>(std::bitset<int> bsetA, std::bitset<int> bsetB)
```

But this is not legal

Comment: `std::bitset` receive a number (`std::size_t`); so `std::bitset<int>` is wrong (and `join2<int, int, int>` too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code works for me. Compiled on Vs2017 and on g++ 7.3

```
// 
// bit_tools.h
// 
#include <bitset>

template <size_t sizeA, size_t sizeB, size_t sizeAB>
std::bitset<sizeAB> join2(std::bitset<sizeA> bsetA,
                           std::bitset<sizeB> bsetB);

// 
// bit_tools.cc
// 
#include "bit_tools.h"

template <size_t sizeA, size_t sizeB, size_t sizeAB>
std::bitset<sizeAB> join2(std::bitset<sizeA> bsetA, std::bitset<sizeB> bsetB) {
    return std::bitset<sizeAB>(bsetA.to_string() + bsetB.to_string());
}

// Here you should provide integer constants instead of type
template
std::bitset<32>  join2<16,16,32>(std::bitset<16> bsetA, std::bitset<16> bsetB);

// 
// main.cc
// 

#include "bit_tools.h"

int main() {

    std::bitset<16> bsetA;
    std::bitset<16> bsetB;

    join2<16,16,32>(bsetA, bsetB);
}
```